Why the text goes under the bottom border when the font increases?
I have been working on some markers overlay on codepen as a concept and now that I have included it on my website I am having issues with some text positioning, basically depending of the text size the text itself goes down in position under its own border (that shouldn't be possible right?).
Here the codepen: https://codepen.io/nebue/pen/LYwVeMo


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap");

body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 200px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.marker {
  --marker-size: 18px;
  --marker-dot-size: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--marker-size);
  height: var(--marker-size);
  border: 1px solid white;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.marker .markerdot {
  width: var(--marker-dot-size);
  height: var(--marker-dot-size);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.marker input[name="markers"] {
  appearance: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.marker .markerlabel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.marker .title {
  --padding-bottom: 4px;
  --border-bottom-size: 1px;
  --abs-x: max(var(--marker-title-x), -1 * var(--marker-title-x));
  --abs-y: max(var(--marker-title-y), -1 * var(--marker-title-y));
  --abs-angle: max(
    var(--marker-title-line-angle),
    -1 * var(--marker-title-line-angle)
  );
  --text-height: calc(1rem + var(--padding-bottom) - var(--border-bottom-size));
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: var(--padding-bottom);
  border-bottom: var(--border-bottom-size) solid white;

  width: fit-content;

  text-wrap: nowrap;

  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &.title-top-right {
    transform: translate(var(--abs-x), calc(var(--abs-y) * -1));
  }

  &.title-top-left {
    transform: translate(calc(var(--abs-x) * -1), calc(var(--abs-y) * -1));
  }

  &.title-bottom-right {
    transform: translate(var(--abs-x), calc(var(--abs-y) - var(--text-height)));
  }

  &.title-bottom-left {
    transform: translate(
      calc(var(--abs-x) * -1),
      calc(var(--abs-y) - var(--text-height))
    );
  }
}

.marker {
  & .title-top-right::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: var(--title-line-length);
    border-top: 1px solid white;

    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: translatey(var(--border-bottom-size))
      rotate(calc(var(--abs-angle) * -1));
  }

  & .title-bottom-right::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--title-line-length);
    border-top: 1px solid white;

    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: translatey(var(--border-bottom-size)) rotate(var(--abs-angle));
  }

  & .title-bottom-left::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--title-line-length);
    border-top: 1px solid white;

    transform-origin: left center;
    transform: translatey(var(--border-bottom-size))
      rotate(calc(var(--abs-angle) * -1));
  }

  & .title-top-left::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: var(--title-line-length);
    border-top: 1px solid white;

    transform-origin: left center;
    transform: translatey(var(--border-bottom-size)) rotate(var(--abs-angle));
  }
}

.marker:hover .markerdot {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1.3px white;
}

.marker:has(input:checked),
.marker label.title:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  & .markerdot {
    transform: scale(1.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1.3px white;
  }

  & label.title {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="marker">
    <label for="marker1" class="title title-bottom-right" style="--marker-title-x: 250px; --marker-title-y: 95px; --marker-title-line-angle: 23deg; --title-line-length: 185px;">
      Your text here
    </label>
    <label class="markerlabel">
      <input id="marker1" type="radio" name="markers">
      <span class="markerdot"></span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="marker">
    <label for="marker2" class="title title-bottom-left" style="--marker-title-x: 250px; --marker-title-y: 95px; --marker-title-line-angle: 23deg; --title-line-length: 185px;">
      Your text here
    </label>
    <label class="markerlabel">
      <input id="marker2" type="radio" name="markers">
      <span class="markerdot"></span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="marker">
    <label for="marker3" class="title title-top-right" style="--marker-title-x: 250px; --marker-title-y: 95px; --marker-title-line-angle: 23deg; --title-line-length: 185px;">
      Your text here
    </label>
    <label class="markerlabel">
      <input id="marker3" type="radio" name="markers">
      <span class="markerdot"></span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="marker">
    <label for="marker4" class="title title-top-left" style="--marker-title-x: 250px; --marker-title-y: 95px; --marker-title-line-angle: -23deg; --title-line-length: 185px;">
      Your text here
    </label>
    <label class="markerlabel">
      <input id="marker4" type="radio" name="markers">
      <span class="markerdot"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>



Marker overlay example in codepen
On my web site look like this:
Faulty marker
I tried to review all the positioning related with this element the parents, that doesn't seem to be the issue and does not make much sense to be, in the end the border belongs to the element and it is only the characters that are misplaced.
I changed the line-height to 0, since I have a value defined for all texts. This move the text just a little bit up. Still not good.
enter image description here
I noticed when the font size changes the position is affected, so the initial font (avobe image) is 16px, when I increment it to 26px it looks like this:
enter image description here
I also noticed tried to change box-sizing from border-box to content-box, in which case I was expecting border-box to work well as in the codepen but no, actually content-box is helping a bit here.
And if I combine the box-size: content-box. with line-height: 0, I get what I expect.
enter image description here
But still any font size change will affect the text in the same way... So, Why this is not working as in the codepen?
I tried to review all the CSS that can affect this and only box-size and line-height seems to really do something, so I couldn't find another CSS interfering. Anyway the way the text overlaps with the bottom border is weird.

Inspect the element in the dev tools.  If the answer is not clear, inspect the elements parents, so on and so forth until you see why the element is moving the way it is moving.  Change CSS properties in the dev tools, disable properties etc, do the same for the parent properties.

Hi @ScottZ,
That's what I did for the whole day.
Anyway I figured it out, it was the parent container height being smaller what pushed the text down. The weird thing is that wasn't happening on the codepen and I couldn't figure out if there is any style causing this on my page.
